# How can I check if the new brake pad will fit my caliper before buying?

Tags: brake-rotor, brake-calipers, brake-pad

I am trying to get a set of [EBC redstuff](https://www.carid.com/ebc-brakes/redstuff-ceramic-low-dust-brake-pads.html?offermpnid=4491818199&view=123456&gclid=CjwKCAjwq4fsBRBnEiwANTahcAlnSfKf_OfRuu3T0mdEahB-h6Jt7v0aEzzgGuV6QJV6kdbjNIm1lBoCRfsQAvD_BwE) brake pads for my 2019 mazda 3 hatch. How can I tell if it would be compatible? And would I need new "sport" oriented rotors with those cooling vents to go with the "sport" brake pads?

I am replacing the stock mazda ones because I prefer a more progressive brake rather than the linear one that comes with the mazda

Comment: Check with make, model and year AND the make of the caliper, as that is not always the same...

Comment: @SolarMike would the specs be on the caliper itself? I can't find it in the owners manual nor online. Could it be because my car is still too new?

Comment: The owner's manual won't say the make of brakes because they put on what is available on the production line... check the name on the caliper... or the style...

Comment: @SolarMike Thank you. And for the pads, the description says FMSI No. D061, and Dimensions 74 x 64 x 14mm. Do I just look at the dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to check the various online parts catalogues such as Mintex, etc...  Compare the image and dimensions in any of these catalogues to the pads physically in the car at the moment.  What you'll then be able to do is cross-reference the catalogue part number to the manufacturers part number and match that up to the EBC catalogue.

I should point out however, if you're intention is to fit EBC Red Stuff pads to improve brake feel, you may find yourself struggling to stop when the car isn't being used hard.  Performance brake pads are typically intended for fast road and track use and when they're not upto operating temperature, you'll find standard pads will perform better.  You might want to look at EBC Green Stuff pads instead.

Comment: Also with track oriented pads, not only do they work best when hot, since they are very aggressive, tend to wear out *much faster* than stock pads. They'll also go through the rotor a lot quicker as well. The Green Stuff pads would be a much better choice for on-road or routine use, IMHO.

Comment: I mainly chose the red stuff over the green because there is a lot less dust from use compared to the green. is the dust from the green stuff pads noticeable? I've always replaced worn out pads with more OEM ones so idk how much dust the green stuff will actually produce.